# Bash regex to match a word folowed by numbers or not

Tags: bash, sed

I want to match this strings `value`, `value1`, `value2`. 
I got the number so far, but I need to match the word with no numbers after, also.

```
sed -e 's/value[0-9]//g'
```

Comment: Try this instead ```sed -e 's/value[0-9]?//g'```.

Comment: If you need arbitrary number of digits (including none): `value[0-9]*'

Comment: @dash-o, Plus signal means one or more of that characters, not zero or more.

Comment: @accdias  I believe that with `sed` (default) basic RE, '?', '+', '(', '{' and '|' need to be escaped to have special meaning. 'value[0-9]?' will match 'value0?', 'value1?', ..., but NOT 'value'.

Comment: @dash-o I tested it localy before posting and it was able to replace all ```value```, including those not ending in a digit. But I see your point. Asterisk is a better option for sure.

Comment: There are many different `sed` variants; what works for you may not work for others. You need a fair amount of experience with different platforms to write properly portable `sed` scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine a multiple expressions into one by separating with semicolons. Hope this helps.

```
sed  's/value[0-9]//g;s/value//g' inputfile
```